# Finding the sum of a variable amount of numbers in a given string

Tags: javascript

I am doing [an exercise on JS Hero website](https://www.jshero.net/en/koans/stringsplit.html):

> Write a function add that takes a string with a summation task and returns its result as a number. A finite number of natural numbers should be added. The summation task is a string of the form '1+19+...+281'.
>
> Example: `add('7+12+100')` should return 119.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
function add (string) {
   let partsArray = string.split("+");
   let added = parseInt(partsArray[0]);
      
   for (let i=0; i<=partsArray.length; i++) {
      added = added + parseInt(partsArray[i]);
   }

   return added;
}
```

It returns NaN. Any ideas how to solve this one?

Answer (score 4):

You were going out of bounds on your array. Also you should just initialize the added to 0 as you start looking at the array from index 0. Note I added some console.logs to give you an idea of how you might debug something like this.

```
function add (string) {
   let partsArray = string.split("+");
   console.log("parts", partsArray);
   let added = 0;
      
   for (let i=0; i<partsArray.length; i++) {
      console.log("i",parseInt(partsArray[i]));
      added += parseInt(partsArray[i]);
   }

   return added;
}
```

If you add the `<=` back and run the code with the console.logs you will see in console the following. Note with the `<=` you have 4 indexes rather than the expected 3. This is because the size is 3 but the array is indexed from zero. When you use `<` you get the expected answer.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why you would want to set added to 0 instead of the first index?

Comment: @janedoe Because in this instance you are starting your loop from 0, so you would be adding the value at zero two times. Also by init to zero and allowing the loop to work from the zeroth index it builds in a bit of error handling. If you passed in an empty array assigning right off the back to the zeroth index could cause issues.

Comment: If you still want to init to the first value (and potentially return "undefined" for an empty array) then you will need to start he index in the for loop to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the reduce method:

```
function add(string) {
  return string.split('+').reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + 
    parseInt(currentValue, 10),0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to start with the first index ..you can do it like below

```
function add (string) {
   let partsArray = string.split("+");
   let added = parseInt(partsArray[0]);   
   for (let i=1; i<partsArray.length; i++) {
      added += parseInt(partsArray[i]);
   }
   return added;
}
```

Comment: - Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. You can read about accepting here: stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add(input) {
    let myinput = input.split("+") //split your value
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < myinput.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + +myinput[i]; //use + for identify the number value
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32697135)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible answer is:

```
function add(str){
    return eval(str)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(given) 
  {
    
    let data=given.split('+');
    
    let nums=data.map(function(num){
        return parseInt(num)
    })
    
    let sum=0
    for(let i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+nums[i];
    }
    console.log( sum)
    
}
add('7+12+100')
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(string) {
  let parts = string.split("+")
  let sum = parseInt(0);

  for(let i=0;i<parts.length;i++){ 
    console.log(parts[i])
    sum = sum + parseInt(parts[i])
  }
  
  return sum
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: You should add explanation.